# Windows 8 change DNS settings after installing Hyper-V

Tags: windows-8, dns, hyper-v

I wanted to change the DNS settings of my PC, so I opened 'network and sharing center' and clicked 'change adapter settings'.

[image]

But to my surprise the properties window looks like this:

[image]

Usually the 'internet protocol version 4' is checked, and usually that's where I can modify DNS settings, etc.

Is this because I installed Hyper-V? If that is so, where can I change DNS settings now?

Comment: Why don't you change it on the `vEthernet (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Virtual Switch)`...

Comment: @ta.speot.is I changed the DNS settings of `vEthernet (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Virtual Switch)` and it worked. So after installing Hyper-V that's the place to change network settings.